# How do I connect a VGA input to my Mac?

Tags: vga

I am *not* talking about connecting a VGA monitor to a Mac. I'm referring to plugging in a VGA output in to my Mac. I want the VGA to show up as a video device, so that I can run a projector's feed through UStream.

What hardware is needed to digitize a VGA input in real time to send for broadcast?

Comment: Does the UStream software give you a clue as to what hardware you need? It looks like you'd just need [UStream Producer Pro](http://www.ustream.tv/producer) and any capture card that fits your budget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a product like this:

[KVM Console to USB 2.0 Portable Laptop Crash Cart Adapter](http://www.networktechinc.com/usb-lap-console.html)

However I don't know if that will show up as a streamable device (or if it's even compatible with Mac). There are also people who have had success buying a webcam and a VGA > Analogue adapter, and wiring the analogue adapter into the webcams electronics to get it back into the computer.

Unfortunately, no real "easy" solution exists.

Comment: Seems like this is what I was looking for. However, I actually ended up using [Ustream Desktop Presenter](http://www.ustream.tv/producer) to send the projector to the computer. Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 2):

I use a product from http://xlr8.com/ to give me a video input on my mac, then use a VGA-to-TV adapter to stream powerpoint over ustream.  Video is really choppy and crappy looking, but for simple non-moving slides, it's OK for ustream.